# Creating an installation for a java project

Tags: java, mysql, database

I created a java project that uses a database to retrieve, edit, and save data. I finished the project using Netbeans and now I want to create an installation out of the project. To do so, I want to include the database to be installed along with the project.
The code I am using to connect to the database is:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql?" + "user=root&password=123";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

The application is working fine on my pc, but I need it to be installed as an executable on other pcs.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Nullsoft Scriptable Install System - http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Comment: MySQL is not designed for this type of 'embedded' use. You are going to find it very difficult to install it and start it reliably before your application launches on consumer PCs. You may wish to investigate other databases such as SQLite or H2 which are designed to operate from a single file or directory.

Comment: Why dont you install MySQL separately on users machines (or ask them to do so)?,and then then add a config file that contains MySQL info like( IP, port, username and password). you can embed a SQL script that generates the database

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a whole database management tool and not suited for an embedded client use. Take a look in the h2 memory database instead.

If you still want to proceed in your path, I would create a archive with your programm and a mysql installation executive. Inside your archive there is a setup script/execute which installs and configures mysql on the client's computer. You want to make it a silent install i.e. there will be wizard and all configuration is done from your installation skript.

Comment: I converted to H2 database. My application is now using H2 and not mySQL. So now what do I have to use to produce the installation?

Comment: Put the H2 Jahr into your installtion file. And start the server with: `java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server`

Comment: I want to create the installation file myself for other users to be able to install it on their PCs. Is there any software to build an installation for my JAVA program? How could I get the .jar file of the database created? What does java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Server do? I have the database created on a directory on computer (C:\Users\MY User\localhost\galllerie.h2.db). I want this to be installed with the java program itself.