# Installation for a college DBMS Project

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, phpmyadmin

I have created a simple database application as a part of my college assignment. I have used Java (Eclipse IDE) and MySQL (command-line and phpMyAdmin) for the purpose of creating and using the database on a stand-alone application. The thing is that my database is stored on the *localhost*.

An easy way to make my application usable on another person's computer would be to convert it into an Executable JAR (since, I am using Java). **However is there any way by means of which I can also install the database directly to the other person's computer (on the *localhost*)?**

Something like an installer or so?

I read online that a simple thing would be to manually install MySQL and create the database. But I don't know PHP and typing the MySQL commands / using phpMyAdmin would be the only choice. But is there any better way to go about doing it?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT1:**
I don't know if this helps but I have no previous knowledge regarding creating installers for projects. All I have done until now has been exported either as an executable JAR or as source code. I am still studying.

**EDIT 2:** [Creating an installation for a java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369448/creating-an-installation-for-a-java-project) <- is a similar question but it does not help my cause. It recommends not using MySQL. Our college has compulsorily asked us to use MySQL and nothing else. That is what they taught us and expect us to work only with it. Please help.

Comment: If you need the DB only for that specific application, you might consider an embedded database such as H2. This way, you can "deliver" the database together with your program.

Comment: You could alternatively use a lightweight database version in your app, such as SQLlite.

Comment: I am not allowed to use anything but MySQL by college.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP here, so don't worry about not knowing it. PHP is just another programming language (a web-based interpreted one), and isn't going to help you install MySQL.

You should probably ask your instructor for assistance, because anything we come up with would be a guess about how they intend for your to operate, whereas they know and have done this before many times. That being said, we can make reasonable guesses toward helping you.

You could probably have one master MySQL installation that all your installed Java applications access. This is probably what you want, rather than installing the MySQL application on each individual computer. Your Java application then connects to your college's MySQL server rather than localhost. This requires configuring the MySQL server for remote access, but if that's what they want you to do they probably have already done so.

The other option is to have an installer that actually installs MySQL and runs a series of scripts to import the expected database structure. I can't imagine this is actually the intention, but there are many different installers that can help with this, and it depends how what platform you're developing for as to which automated installation tool might work best for you. You can, to a large degree, script the installation of the official source, so you may simply be able to tweak that once you find the customization options you need, then wrap that in a simple shell script which first installs MySQL then imports your database structure. I can't imagine this is what your school intends, but that's how you would do it if it were. That or Chef, Puppet, or your distribution's built-in package manager. Too many options to cover them all thoroughly here.